# regex toplevel domain with/without numbers

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to use the regex if=then|else statement.

This code:

```
(?(?=(.*)[.][a-zA-Z]{2}$)(.*)[.](.*)[.][a-zA-Z]{2}$|(.*)[.](.*)[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$)
```

should ask for the last 2 characters after the dot.

Mentioning the site:
 https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html 
 
the syntax should be right?

If there are only two characters in the top level domain none of these two is allowed to be a number. 
E.g. 
www.url.a1  should be wrong. 
www.url.aa  should be valid

If there are more than 2 letters after the dot all letters and numbers should be allowed. 
E.g. 
www.morelettersandnumbers.asfh1537 should be valid

Shouldn't this code do this or do I miss something?

Edit: I am using Java and I try to do it without the pattern method.

Comment: It will be useful to analyze more if you mention the programming language you are using here.

Comment: `.*` will match a dot also, so it's hard to really predict what this will match in the grand scheme of things.  Probably you can improve things by changing the wildcards to `[^.]*` to avoid skipping a dot when you don't mean to.

Comment: There is no "if-then-else" syntax in regex. What you can do is `this|that|other thing` where `this` will take precedence over `that` and either of those over `other thing`.  You can add negative lookaheads like `(?!lol)` to exercise additional control over each of the alternatives (assuming you are using a regex dialect which supports this syntax in the first place, which is not clear from your question -- see the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for instructions for properly asking a well-defined question with enough details).

Comment: Your regex appears to require there to be two dots in every match, which does not seem to agree with the prose description (many domains are directly beneath a top-level domain, like `stackoverflow.ru`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! This should be a URL validation where the toplevel domain either has 2 characters (only letters) or infinite letters with numbers included.

Comment: Those are not answers, they are comments, asking you to further [edit] your question to clarify the things which are still unclear. Thanks for specifying the language already.

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/ it's an excellent visual tool for developing regular expressions.

Comment: I was trying it with regex101 but I can not find the problem. There must be a problem in the semantic of the code i guess.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Your question should remain strictly a question, though you are welcome to post (and even accept) an answer of your own if none of the current answers satisfy you. Your edits are still retrievable from the [revision history.](/posts/54194486/revisions)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am sorry, I am new to this site and do not know the behavior of formatting yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you refer to is a little bit muddy. The `(?=...)` lookahead basically allows you to specify an additional constraint on the string you want to match, but in this particular case, you don't need more constraints than you already have.

```
([^.]+[.])*[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{2}$
```

matches a domain (with optional subdomains) which contains a letters-only two-character ccTLD; and

```
([^.]+[.])*[^.]+[.][-A-Za-z0-9]{3,}$
```

matches a domain (with oiptional subdomains) which contains more than three characters, letters or numbers.

Combining the two, factoring out the optional subdomain to a non-capturing group, yields

```
(?:[^.]+[.])*([^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{2}|[^.]+[.][-A-Za-z0-9]{3,})$
```

which is still arguably wrong for actual top-level domains which have multiple labels (like `co.uk` or `gob.mx`) and doesn't allow for single-letter top-level domains; but it probably does what you are asking for.